# is it better to separate user entity from actual client information

Tags: symfony

I'm currently developing a full web client administration system on Symfony2. However, the question whether to create a User entity and a separate Client entity or have the User entity manage all client information (like it's credit state) remains unanswered.

From what I've gathered, using a separate entity for each thing permits me to have a better separation between the login system (which needs a User entity with basic properties) and the bussiness logic (which needs a Client entity with all the properties a client in the real world has). However, that would mean having a bigger footprint (if they were saved in a database, I would have to use a join statement) than having a single entity contain all properties.

What would you recommend in this case? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the user login and system you can use [FOSuserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

If your clients also need to login in same system then i would say that you go for

https://github.com/netmeansnet/NmnMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Then you can have separate class for each type os users and define custom properties

They all will use same basic attributes like username , password and then you can have extra information for client Enitity